# How do I get my inventory list to store int, string and Sprite? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a script in Unity for a small prototype I'm making. It is an inventory script that is meant to add inventory items the player picks up in the game. How it works(or how I intend it to work), is the inventory script has a Scriptable Object class called ItemData, in which I store the string(Items name), int(quantity of said item) and a Sprite(items Icon). The following code is stored on the Player Controller

Here is the following code that I have, and so far, I get an argument exception error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class ItemData : ScriptableObject
{
    public string itemName;
    public int amountOfItem;
    public Sprite itemIcon;
}

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ItemData> items = new List<ItemData>();

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Item"))
        {
            ItemData itemData = other.GetComponent<ItemData>();

            if (itemData != null)
            {
                items.Add(itemData);
                Destroy(other.gameObject); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a a list that stores ItemData, when it adds more ItemData into the list once the player collides with a game object tagged "Item". I understand that the list might just be storing the ItemData scriptable objects, but I have no idea where to start when it comes to decoupling(?) the int, string and Sprite, so that the inspector displays each individual element, and allowing me to easily reference the inventory list in future scripts for things such as item consumption and etc.

So far, this is what I have, not much has changed but I considered trying to create instance parameters, but I might have honestly just not done that at all xD

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditorInternal.Profiling.Memory.Experimental;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class ItemData : ScriptableObject
{
    public int amountOfItem;
    public string itemName;
    public Sprite itemIcon;
}

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ItemData> items = new List<ItemData>();
    public ItemData itemData;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Item"))
        {
            itemData = other.GetComponent<ItemData>();

            if (itemData != null)
            {
                Additem(itemData.amountOfItem,
                          itemData.itemName,
                          itemData.itemIcon);
                Destroy(other.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Additem(int quantity, string name, Sprite icon)
    {
        ItemData item = new ItemData();
        item.amountOfItem = quantity;
        item.itemName = name;
        item.itemIcon = icon;
    }
}
```

Comment: well  a key problem here seems is your inventory is trying to be stored on every item.  so each item will likely only list itself...

Comment: Hi @BugFinder, thanks for the reply, I included an edit to inform that this code is on the Player Character, so unless I am truly missing something, the inventory list is only stored on the player, no other object, and the object that player "collects" is destroyed.

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: @DanielBrunner, Normally I would know how to find the line that is causing an error in the console, but this error simply prints:
ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'ItemData' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent[T] () (at <10871f9e312b442cb78b9b97db88fdcb>:0)

Comment: Apologies, I did actually find which line it is,

`ItemData itemData = other.GetComponent<ItemData>();`

Comment: right, its not a componet. its a scriptable object...

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, you mixed too many things together.

- Split item instance parameters and common parameters.
- Let your item instance contain the link to a scriptable object with a description that will be the same for any instance of this object in the game (it can contain an icon, price, max durability, etc. in dependence on your game design).
- Let your item instance contain item parameters that are unique for this instance (for example, current durability, enchantments, etc.).

The amount also seems like something specific to the item instance, not common for every instance. However, it can be the same for every instance of a pile of coins with an amount of 50 in your game design, so you have to decide what to store and where.

I mean something like this:

```cs
class CommonItemData : ScriptableObject
{
    public string ItemName;
    public Sprite ItemIcon;
    
    // some other parameters that are the same and do not changes for every single instance of this item
    public int MaxDurability;
    public int Price;
    ...
}

public class IngameItem
{
    // link to a data that does not change from instance to instance
    public CommonItemData BaseItemData;

    // instance specific data
    public int CurDurability;
    public List<Enchantments> Enchantments;
    ...
    // etc.
}

class InventoryItem
{
    public IngameItem Item;

    // don't think that this parameter is needed somewhere outside of inventory
    public int amountOfItem;
}

// lets think that this script is attached to a gameobject visualizing your item somewhere available to be put on and placed to inventory 
// this is only one veriant, it can be done in different ways
public ItemView : MonoBehaviour
{
    SpriteRenderer _renderer;    
    InventoryItem _item;

    public InventoryItem Item => _item;

    public Init(InventoryItem item)
    {
        _item = item;
        _renderer.Sprite = item.BaseItemData.ItemIcon;
    }
}

etc.
```

With such a structure you will need to get `ItemView` script from the game object you want to put on, get InventoryItem from it, and add this InventoryItem instance to your inventory. So, your inventory will look like:

```cs
public class Inventory
{
    List<InventoryItem> _items = new List<InventoryItem>();

    public void AddItem(InventoryItem item)
    {
        _items.Add(item);
    }
    
    ...
    // whatever you also need from your inventory
}
```

In other features the same classes can be used. For example, if you want to create some popup with info about any ingame item in your inventory, you just need to take IngameItem instance from the InventoryItem instance and pass it to your popup. And so on and so forth.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will try my best to implement the following you just informed me about and will report back if its fixed. I am relatively new to coding and I don't do it all the time, so bear with me as I try to implement your changes! =)

Comment: I have included an edit to the original post attempting to implement what you recommended, at least a part of it =)

Comment: added code examples about what I mean